# Prolog predicate regarding list manipulation

Tags: prolog, predicate

E.g: given 3 statement:

```
car(toyota,[sedan,5_seater,head_rest]).
car(nissan,[4_seater,sedan,2_door,head_rest,blue]).
car(peugeot,[head_rest,sedan,5_seater,sun_roof]).
```

How to write a Prolog predicate `items(A, X, Y)` that is true if A is the list car that contain all the parts in X but do not contain any of the parts in Y.

Really hope somebody can help me. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see [subtract](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=subtract/3)/3

```
items(A, X, Y) :- subtract(X, Y, A).
```

if you keep your lists sorted (i.e. like sets), [ord_subtract](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=ord_subtract/3)/3 is a much better alternative

*edit*: sorry for the useless answer, here is the amended one.
The relevant list processing predicate is [intersection](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=intersection/3)/3, while [setof](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=allsolutions)/3 is a powerful list 'constructor'.

items/3 could be written in this way

```
items(A, Present, Miss) :-
    setof(Car, Parts^(car(Car, Parts),
              intersection(Parts, Present, Present),
              intersection(Parts, Miss, [])), A).
```

since your database is a bit meager, to test I enter

```
?- items(L,[sedan],[blue]).
L = [peugeot, toyota].
```

Comment: Oops. You're right, I didn't read your question correctly, my answer completely misses the point... editing now...